# Android Download AsyncTask freezes my app for a long time

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

When I start the app I only see a white screen for about 15 seconds. I think this is because the asynctask is still trying to reach the server in the background although it is currently not online. Is there any way to solve the problem that the user gets a message saying that an attempt is being made to connect to the server or that a time limit is being introduced?

I have built this up so that at the beginning of the app a file is downloaded in which the latest version of a database is stored if it is larger than the one currently installed daas is downloaded in downloadAvailableDatabase() (I still have to do the last one).

Here are the important parts of the two files:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Initialization();

    DataManager.Initialization(context);
}
```

**DataManager.java**

```
public static void Initialization(Context context){
    try {
        if (isNetworkAvailable(context)){
            files_path = Objects.requireNonNull(context.getExternalFilesDir("")).toString();

            IntegerDownloadTask integerDownloadTask = new IntegerDownloadTask();
            Integer database_version = getDatabaseVersion(context);
            Integer available_database_version = integerDownloadTask.execute(database_version_download_url).get();

            if (database_version < available_database_version){
                downloadAvailableDatabase();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("Error", e.toString());
    }
}
private static Integer getDatabaseVersion(Context context){
    File versionFile = new File(files_path, database_version_filename);

    if(versionFile.exists()){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(versionFile));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                stringBuilder.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
            return Integer.parseInt(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(versionFile);
                stream.write("0".getBytes());
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception ignored){}
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(versionFile);
            stream.write("0".getBytes());
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored){}
        return 0;
    }
}
private static void downloadAvailableDatabase(){

    }
private static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        assert connectivityManager != null;
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    } catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use the .get() method on an asynctask as it is not async anymore then as you have seen.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding the progressBar in your activity
In your activity xml file add the following code:

```
<ProgressBar
 android:id="@+id/simpleProgressBar"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

then in OnCreate function in your activity initialise the progressBar and set the visibility as visible

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Initialization();

progressbar=findViewById(R.id.simpleProgressBar)
progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

DataManager.Initialization(context);
}
```

then in your async Task set the visibility of the progressBar to gone in onPostExecute Method